# In the truffle console, how to set and get current account?

Tags: truffle, accounts, testrpc

I'm using the `$ truffle console`.
I can see my available accounts using `truffle(development)> web3.eth.accounts`.

But when I run some smart contract code, which account is running the contract?

And, how can I change the account which is running the contracts in the truffle console?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In truffle console:

```
var accounts;
// in web front-end, use an onload listener and similar to this manual flow ... 
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err,res) { accounts = res; });

var account1 = accounts[0]; // first account
var account2 = accounts[1]; // second account, if exists
...

var contract;
Contract.deployed()
.then(function(response) {
  contract = response;
  return contract.function(arg1, arg2, {from: account2}); // send txn from 2nd account
```

In Truffle tests you can start out with accounts passed in for convenience:

```
contract("basic test pattern", function(accounts) {
  owner = accounts[0];
  ...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did that bug msg.sender is always `'0x00'`

Comment: Using the contract of truffle unbox example, and following your specifications it gives this error: 
`MetaCoin Error: invalid address (arg="receiver", coderType="address", value=undefined)`

. Actually `accounts` variable successfully stores two addresses. I used accounts[1] to transfer using the .sendCoin method of the MetaCoin contract, uint as 2nd argument with the quantity to transfer, and `{from: accounts[0]}`. solc is 0.5.16

Answer (score 6):

Now you can use `await` to simplify code:

```
let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
```